# Can't include js file for client slide validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I installed gem 'client_side_validations', run bundle and run rails g client_side_validations:install

Installation DIDN"T create any js files, so I created them and put code from HitHub in my assets/javascript folder.

added line into application.js

```
  //= require rails.validations
```

added line into application.html.erb

```
       <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "rails.validations", "rails.validations.custom" %>
```

and validation isn't working online(using Devise gem)

In my view:

```
 <%= form_for resource, ... , :validate => true do |f| %>
```

In GoogleChrome console logs:

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
"/assets/javascripts/rails.validations.custom.js"
"/assets/javascripts/rails.validations.js"
```

What I missed ?

Comment: Do you have the "rails.validations.custom" file in your assets/js folder?

Comment: The generator didn't created this file, so I created file and put code from github.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the command `rails g client_side_validations:install` it seems to only generate the initializer `config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb`.

However, on the [github page](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) under the "Install" section they mention the command for copying the javascript file to the project's assets: `rails g client_side_validations:copy_assets`

**Note:** If you run Rails >= 3.1 you don't need to add the javascript file in the layout anymore, it should be sufficient to have `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` as long as the application.js contains the line `//= require_tree .` which includes all javascript files under `app/assets/javascripts` directory.

In the initializer `client_side_validations.rb` file you also need to uncomment the last block:

```
# Uncomment the following block if you want each input field to have the validation messages attached.
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  ...
end
```

Once you have done this you need to restart the server for the changes to take effect.