# What gem better : jCheck and client_side_validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I want to compare them: both of gems have advantages and disadvantages.

For example in client_side_validations more clear and more Ruby to create custom notifications,BUT I have problems with its installation [Can't include js file for client slide validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029197/cant-include-js-file-for-client-slide-validation) . It is very big minus for me)

jCheck more beatiful, but I need to use more jQuery to use it.

One more: I can't get where all notifications (jCheck) are stored ?

I want to ask : what gem is better  for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon what version of Rails you are using will determine if you can use ClientSideValidations. I haven't had the free time to complete the Rails 3.2 update. Very sorry.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now I'm using jQuery plugin. It is not bad for me.